# Read XML Tags using SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

```
<University>
  <RegistrationCode>12859</RegistrationCode>
  <Colleges>
    <College>
      <CollegeCode>0001</CollegeCode>
      <CollegeName>NIMS</CollegeName>
    </College>
    <College>
      <CollegeCode>0002</CollegeCode>
      <CollegeName>OXFORD</CollegeName>
    </College>
  </Colleges>
</University>
```

I want extract below out put from above XML using SQL Query. Can someone help me on this?

```
RegistrationCode   CollegeCode      CollegeName
-----------------------------------------------
12859              0001             NIMS
12859              0002             OXFORD
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680259/parse-xml-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<University>
<RegistrationCode>12859</RegistrationCode>
<Colleges>
<College>
<CollegeCode>0001</CollegeCode>
<CollegeName>NIMS</CollegeName>
</College>
<College>
<CollegeCode>0002</CollegeCode>
<CollegeName>OXFORD</CollegeName>
</College>
</Colleges>
</University>'

SELECT
    RegistrationCode = Univ.value('(RegistrationCode)[1]', 'int'),
    CollegeCode = Colleges.value('(CollegeCode)[1]', 'int'),
    CollegeName = Colleges.value('(CollegeName)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM 
    @input.nodes('University') AS XTbl(Univ)
CROSS APPLY
    Univ.nodes('Colleges/College') AS XTbl2(Colleges)
```

That gives me your desired output.

Basically, you need to first have a list of `<University>` nodes (just one here) to get the registration code, and then from that `<University>` node you grab the `<Colleges>/<College>` subnodes using `CROSS APPLY` and you grab the college code and name from those subnodes