# How to split a string into multiple columns and then into multiple rows

Tags: sql, string

I have a procedure which returns a string which is like below

```
<USAGESTARTT=1387847400,USAGEENDT=1387849200,EVENTCOUNT=8,EVENTDURATION=247996,DISKSPACEUSED=0,BANDWIDTHOUT=0,BANDWIDTHCDN=0,HOURSUSED=0,AMOUNT=41332.66,RECYCLED_AMOUNT=0,NUM_RECYCLED_CDR=0,PROCESS_NAME=CP_RAX_RAT_SUSP,SERVICE_TYPE=CLOUD_BKUP>,<USAGESTARTT=0,USAGEENDT=1386032400,EVENTCOUNT=8,EVENTDURATION=74262,DISKSPACEUSED=0,BANDWIDTHOUT=0,BANDWIDTHCDN=0,HOURSUSED=0,AMOUNT=99.02,RECYCLED_AMOUNT=0,NUM_RECYCLED_CDR=0,PROCESS_NAME=CP_RAX_RAT_SUSP,SERVICE_TYPE=CLOUD_SRVR_UPTIME>,
```

This actually a set of two rows of data sets concatenated with each other. Individually they look like

String 1

```
<USAGESTARTT=1387847400,USAGEENDT=1387849200,EVENTCOUNT=8,EVENTDURATION=247996,DISKSPACEUSED=0,BANDWIDTHOUT=0,BANDWIDTHCDN=0,HOURSUSED=0,AMOUNT=41332.66,RECYCLED_AMOUNT=0,NUM_RECYCLED_CDR=0,PROCESS_NAME=CP_RAX_RAT_SUSP,SERVICE_TYPE=CLOUD_BKUP>,
```

String 2

```
<USAGESTARTT=0,USAGEENDT=1386032400,EVENTCOUNT=8,EVENTDURATION=74262,DISKSPACEUSED=0,BANDWIDTHOUT=0,BANDWIDTHCDN=0,HOURSUSED=0,AMOUNT=99.02,RECYCLED_AMOUNT=0,NUM_RECYCLED_CDR=0,PROCESS_NAME=CP_RAX_RAT_SUSP,SERVICE_TYPE=CLOUD_SRVR_UPTIME>,
```

My requirment is i want to split this string first into different rows and then split each row into multiple columns where the string before '=' is the column name and the string after '=' is the value which needs to be inserted into the column. For eg:- In string 'USAGESTARTT=0' USAGESTARTT is the column name and 0 is the value in the column USAGESTARTT. This example shows only two rows but my procedure can return multiple rows concatenated with each other.

Can you please suggest a solution to this requirement?

Comment: What have you tried? Surely splitting strings in SQL has been done thousands of times before and is searchable on the web. StackOverflow is for specific issues that you encounter while writing/running your code.

Answer (score 1):

I use this TVF for splitting strings:

```
CREATE function dbo.split (@value varchar(8000),@delim varchar(8000))
returns table
as
return
(
select d.value,
       d.orders,
       ivalue = convert(int, case when isnumeric(d.value)=1 and d.value not like '%[^0-9 +-]%' and len(replace(replace(replace(d.value,' ',''),'-',''),'+',''))<=10 then case when convert(bigint,d.value) between -2147483648 and 2147483647 then d.value end end)

    from
        (
            select   
                    value= replace(substring(value,
                                            idx,
                                            case when cnt>=0 then cnt end 
                                         )
                                 ,char(1),'')
                    ,orders=( datalength(left(value,idx-1))-datalength(replace(left(value,idx-1),@delim,''))
                            )/datalength(@delim)
                from (
                       select number
                             ,idx
                             ,cnt = charindex(@delim,value, number + 1) - number - datalength(@delim)
                             ,value 
                          from 
                                (
                                   select number
                                         ,idx = number + datalength(@delim)
                                         ,value = (select @delim+char(1)+@value+char(1)+@delim)
                                      from dbo.s_value
                                        where number between 1 and datalength( (select @delim+char(1)+@value+char(1)+@delim) ) - datalength(@delim)

                                ) t            
                          where substring(t.value, number, datalength(@delim)) = @delim         
                     ) t             
       ) d          
)

GO
```

Use it this way:

```
select * from dbo.split(@YOUR_STRING,'>,<')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you can put the string in a variable of type XML and then parse this XML, see [Parse XML in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680259/parse-xml-in-sql-server) for an example.