# How to extract an XML Attribute from an XML varchar string using TSQL in SQL Server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have a `varchar` column with a XML string like the one below. I need to extract the data within the "string" element of `<void property="request">`

In this example, here is the value I need to extract:

```
This is the data I need to extract right here.  Testing 123, Testing 1234
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<java version="1.6.0_20" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder"> 
 <object class="java.util.HashMap"> 
  <void method="put"> 
   <string>data</string> 
   <object class="com.globo.abc.process.eb.data.ManualProcessData"> 
    <void property="caseId"> 
     <long>8406</long> 
    </void> 
    <void property="clientId"> 
     <long>25020</long> 
    </void> 
    <void property="context"> 
     <object class="java.util.HashMap"> 
      <void method="put"> 
       <string>TARGET_GROUP</string> 
       <long>102131</long> 
      </void> 
      <void method="put"> 
       <string>TYPE</string> 
       <string>TICKLER</string> 
      </void> 
     </object> 
    </void> 
    <void property="groupStepDefinitionId"> 
     <long>10274</long> 
    </void> 
    <void property="owner"> 
     <string>2256</string> 
    </void> 
    <void property="request"> 
     <string>This is the data I need to extract right here.  Testing 123, Testing 1234</string> 
    </void> 
    <void property="stepDefinitionName"> 
     <string>Manual Task</string> 
    </void> 
   </object> 
  </void> 
 </object> 
 </java>
```

Comment: With tweezers Mono Hijo

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server or any database scripting language has an odd notion of 'collection' of data, they're called tables.  In order to iterate over a collection of data you'll need to use a cursor and pick through the string. blah blah blah.

If you are trying to pull out a single known token then using charindex, substr, etc.

If you have multiple tokens you'll have to do the cursor and charindex, etc.

Or change or you datatype to xml

[Parse XML in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680259/parse-xml-in-sql-server)