# SQL Parse an xml string

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, parsing

I have a bunch of XMLs that I need to parse with SQL.

The XML can take on multiple forms:

```
<Grandparent>
    <parent>
      <child1>something</child1>
      <child2>something</child2>
    </parent>
</Grandparent>
```

or

```
<Grandparent>
      <child1>something</child1>
      <child2>something</child2>
</Grandparent>
```

Additionally, the number of "child" nodes is variable and there is no way of knowing before hand how many children there are.

What i have done so far is:

```
@xml.nodes('/Grandparent')
```

which returns either the `<parent>` node and children or simply the `child` nodes depending on the format of the xml.

The version of SQL and the fact that i'm writing it as an SQL function seems to mean that trying to get `value`as shown in [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680259/parse-xml-in-sql-server) does not work.

Therefore, I decided to parse the string. Essentially, I look for `<` and take the substring from there until `>` for the node name. Then I take anything between `>` and `</` for the value. I do so in a while loop until the xml string is finished. It works perfectly unless the xml has that `parent` node.

I don't know how to determine whether that `parent` node is there and how to ignore it if it is. This is where I am stuck.

What I want to get in either case is:

```
Node   | Value
child1 | something
child2 | something
```

etc for as many child nodes that there is.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Still not clear that if you can do `@xml.nodes('/Grandparent')`, why then you can't get `value` as shown in that answer link? And given that 2 samples what is the output you expect to get?

Comment: @Politank-Z yes! MS SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use descendant axis `//` to get child nodes at any level depth within a parent node.

Another useful xpath syntax for this task is `local-name()` which return current context node/attribute's name without namespace :

```
select c.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') as 'node'
        , c.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as 'value'
from @xml.nodes('/Grandparent//*[not(*)]') as T(c)
```

This xpath bit `//*[not(*)]` means select descendant nodes that doesn't have child node, in other words select the inner most descendant.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/5023)**

Comment: '/Grandparent//*[not(*)]' is all i needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here with two assumptions; your question isn't clear about the following:

1. I'm assuming that your child nodes have the same name (e.g., child, not child1 and child2), and
2. You want a SQL statement that returns 1 child per row.

If either of those assumptions is incorrect, this answer won't help :)

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<Grandparent>
    <parent>
      <child>something</child>
      <child>something</child>
    </parent>
</Grandparent>'


SELECT x.value('.[1]', 'varchar(100)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('/Grandparent//child') t(x)


SET @xml= '<Grandparent>
      <child>something</child>
      <child>something</child>
</Grandparent>'


SELECT x.value('.[1]', 'varchar(100)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('/Grandparent//child') t(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'
    <Grandparent>
        <parent>
          <child1>something</child1>
          <child2>something</child2>
        </parent>
    </Grandparent>';

SELECT
     child.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') AS Node
    ,child.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS value
FROM @xml.nodes('//*[self::child1 or self::child2]') AS ansestor(child);

SET @xml = N'
    <Grandparent>
          <child1>something</child1>
          <child2>something</child2>
    </Grandparent>';

SELECT
     child.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') AS Node
    ,child.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS value
FROM @xml.nodes('//*[self::child1 or self::child2]') AS ansestor(child);
```