# TSQL to extract column data in a where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have the following query that extracts some column data and also extracts everything between 2 xml tags in a column.

```
Use Database
DECLARE @First VARCHAR(15), @Second VARCHAR(15)
SET @First = '<InstrumentID>'
SET @Second = '</InstrumentID>'

SELECT out_interface_id, msg_id , 
SUBSTRING(xml_msg, CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) + LEN(@First), 
     CHARINDEX(@Second, xml_msg) - 
     CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) - 
     LEN(@First)) as InstrumentID,
msg_type, xml_msg, CAST(xml_msg AS XML) as [Quick_XML], 
date_received,status, last_modified, environment,
transaction_closed_date
from Table1 with (nolock)
where msg_type in ('BALMIS','ACCTV21') 
and date_received >= CAST(GETDATE() -1 as DATE)
and date_received < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
order by date_received desc
```

Now, I want to be able to add to the where clause: and InstrumentID = 'ABC123'

This should be simple but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily. And be careful throwing that NOLOCK hint around. It brings a lot more issues to the table than most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

```
select *
from 
(
    SELECT out_interface_id, msg_id , 
    SUBSTRING(xml_msg, CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) + LEN(@First), 
         CHARINDEX(@Second, xml_msg) - 
         CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) - 
         LEN(@First)) as InstrumentID,
    msg_type, xml_msg, CAST(xml_msg AS XML) as [Quick_XML], 
    date_received,status, last_modified, environment,
    transaction_closed_date
    from Table1 with (nolock)
    where msg_type in ('BALMIS','ACCTV21') 
    and date_received >= CAST(GETDATE() -1 as DATE)
    and date_received < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
) x
where x.InstrumentID = 'ABC123'
order by date_received desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference an alias from the `SELECT` list within your `WHERE` clause. You would need to recreate the same string result in the same manor used in your `SELECT` list:

```
Use Database
DECLARE @First VARCHAR(15), @Second VARCHAR(15)
SET @First = '<InstrumentID>'
SET @Second = '</InstrumentID>'

SELECT out_interface_id, msg_id , 
SUBSTRING(xml_msg, CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) + LEN(@First), 
     CHARINDEX(@Second, xml_msg) - 
     CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) - 
     LEN(@First)) as InstrumentID,
msg_type, xml_msg, CAST(xml_msg AS XML) as [Quick_XML], 
date_received,status, last_modified, environment,
transaction_closed_date
from Table1 with (nolock)
where msg_type in ('BALMIS','ACCTV21') 
and date_received >= CAST(GETDATE() -1 as DATE)
and date_received < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
and SUBSTRING(xml_msg, CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) + LEN(@First), 
     CHARINDEX(@Second, xml_msg) - 
     CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) - 
     LEN(@First)) = 'ABC123'
order by date_received desc;
```

Also, when dealing with XML, it might be better to work with it as XML rather than as a string. I am more familiar with Oracle in this case, but here is a SO entry that touches on the subject: [Parse XML in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680259/parse-xml-in-sql-server)