# xquery to return the element name

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @xml = '
<root>
    <a>
        <DATE_OF_BIRTH> 19871224</DATE_OF_BIRTH> 
        <DRIVER> MIKE </DRIVER> 
    </a>
    <a>
        <DATE_OF_BIRTH> 19881124</DATE_OF_BIRTH> 
        <DRIVER> TOM </DRIVER> 
    </a>
    <a>
        <DATE_OF_BIRTH> 19770601</DATE_OF_BIRTH> 
        <DRIVER> DAVID </DRIVER> 
    </a>
</root>'

select x.value('.','varchar(100)')
from @xml.nodes('//a') as T(X)
```

I want to use xquery to return the element name

The result like this

DATE_OF_BIRTH

DRIVER

How can I make this happen?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is the same answer you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680259/parse-xml-in-sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try the following:

```
select X.query('local-name(.)')
from @xml.nodes('//a/*') as T(X)
```

it will return:

```
DATE_OF_BIRTH
DRIVER
DATE_OF_BIRTH
DRIVER
DATE_OF_BIRTH
DRIVER
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `local-name()` (or `name()` if you want to include the namespace), so it should be

```
//a/*/local-name()
```