# Function or procedure in SQL Server 2014 that can read the content between the tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need a function or procedure in SQL Server 2014 that can read the content between (`<?>`) the sign tags for this example.

Thanks.

```
<ul>how are you?</ul>
```

Output1: should be `ul` or `/ul`

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this the extent of the text?  If these tags be buried in a larger HTML document, then should look for a parser.

Comment: You could cast the input as XML and use something like the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2274091/5552667 (depending on your needs).

Comment: MR.tim , HTML document.help me create func or procedure for Parser .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `local-name` XPath [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190650.aspx):

```
DECLARE @x xml = '<ul>how are you?</ul>'

SELECT  s.d.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(100)') as TagName,
        s.d.value('.','nvarchar(100)') as SomeValue
FROM @x.nodes('/*') as s(d)
```

Output:

```
TagName SomeValue
ul      how are you?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you requirement is too simple to just read content between a tag then you can use the following logic:

```
declare @str varchar(200) = '<ul>how are you?</ul>'
select SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX('<', @str) + 1, CHARINDEX('>', @str) - CHARINDEX('<', @str) -1)
```

However, this will not work if you have multiple tags in the same string.
If you need to handle more complex scenario you can use xquery. I think this link might help you to do so: [xquery to return the element name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711037/xquery-to-return-the-element-name?noredirect=1&lq=1)