# Parsing XML from returned field in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have a field called `xml` that contains some data that I need to extract. The contents of the `xml` field look like this:

```
<p>
  <k>Attribute Name</k>
  <v>Attribute Value</v>
</p>
<p>
  <k>Attribute Name 2</k>
  <v>Attribute Value 2</v>
</p>
<p>
  <k>Attribute Name 3</k>
  <v>Attribute Value 3</v>
</p>
<p>... and so on ...</p>
```

Is there a way I can write my query to extract `Attribute Value 2` in SQL? Is this a normal practice with vendors?

EDIT:

I'm able to query off the xml field using `m.[xml].value('/p[2]','varchar(max)'` but I cannot figure out a way to grab the direct neighbor of the node key I am looking for. For example, I want to grab `<v>Attribute Value 2</v>` but search off `<k>Attribute Name 2</k>`

Comment: I don't think it's `normal practice`, i think it's a `bad practice`. `sqlserver` is a database engine not a parsing engine. Even though, you should look a this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680259/parse-xml-in-sql-server

Comment: Yes, this is ultimately a duplicate of [Parse XML in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680259/parse-xml-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Use `xml.nodes('/p') as p(x)` to retrieve all of the `p` elements, then use `p.x.value(...)` to retrieve the key and value.

If you are only looking to extract specific keys, use XPath to filter and retrieve the value: `/p[k[1]/text() = "foo"]/v[1]/text()`

Answer (score 1):

You did not accept any answer yet, might be, that the existing answers did not really help...

If I get this correctly, you want to read the *value* (=`<v>`) to a given *key* (=`<k>`). Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
  N'<p>
      <k>Attribute Name</k>
      <v>Attribute Value</v>
    </p>
    <p>
      <k>Attribute Name 2</k>
      <v>Attribute Value 2</v>
    </p>
    <p>
      <k>Attribute Name 3</k>
      <v>Attribute Value 3</v>
    </p>';

DECLARE @Search NVARCHAR(100)=N'Attribute Name 2';

SELECT @xml.value(N'(/p[k/text()=sql:variable("@Search")]/v/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)');
```

The key-name you are looking for is set to a variable `@Search`.

The `XQuery` is looking for a `<p>`, where there is a `<k>` which has got the text you are looking for.

Then the `<v>` below the `<p>` is read and returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XQuery syntax to query the table directly and the get value out of the xml.

Example :

```
-- using a table variable for the example
declare @TestTable table (id int identity(1,1), [xml] XML);
insert into @TestTable ([xml]) values (N'<p>
  <k>Attribute Name</k>
  <v>Attribute Value</v>
</p>
<p>
  <k>Attribute Name 2</k>
  <v>Attribute Value 2</v>
</p>
<p>
  <k>Attribute Name 3</k>
  <v>Attribute Value 3</v>
</p>'),
(N'<p>
  <k>Attribute Name 4</k>
  <v>Attribute Value 4</v>
</p>');

DECLARE @AttributeName nvarchar(30) = N'Attribute Name 2';

select id, [xml].query('p[k/text() = sql:variable("@AttributeName")]/v').value('.','nvarchar(max)') as [value]
from @TestTable
where [xml].query('p[k/text() = sql:variable("@AttributeName")]').value('.','nvarchar(max)') != '';
```

Returns :

```
id value 
-- -------------------
1  Attribute Value 2
```

Comment: One should not use the *deep search* (with `//`) if there's no reason for this... Your `XQuery` can be done a bit simpler...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

#### Filtering key with predicate on xquery expression

Use an xquery expression with a [predicate](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/xquery/0596006349/ch04s02.html) to filter to `<p>` nodes that contain a `<k>` child node with the desired string literal (i.e. "Attribute Name 2") using the [value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) function:

```
SELECT m.xml.value('(/p[k/text()="Attribute Name 2"]/v/text())[1]',N'varchar(max)')
from m
```

See it demonstrated in [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a45d6/81).

And if there is a possibility of unicode characters in the data, prefix the xquery string with `N` and select the value as `nvarchar(max)`:

```
SELECT m.xml.value(N'(/p[k/text()="Attribute Name 2"]/v/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
from m
```

#### Select key and value as fields and apply WHERE condition

Borrowing from the second query in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10344601/1575353), [CROSS APPLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) can be used in a sub-query with [.nodes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) to select the text of the `<k>` and `<v>` nodes as fields using [value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type).

Then in the outer-query, a *WHERE* condition can be added to restrict `<p>` nodes to only those with a `<k>` with text *Attribute Name 2*.

```
select [key], value
from (
    select x.value('(k/text())[1]','varchar(max)') as [key],
    x.value('(v/text())[1]','varchar(max)') as value
    FROM m
    CROSS APPLY xml.nodes('//p') as p(x)
) as Result
where [key] = 'Attribute Name 2'
```

See a demonstration of this in [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a45d6/69).

This could be simplified by removing the sub-query and just selecting the text from the `<v>` node where the text of the `<k>` node matches the search string:

```
SELECT x.value('(v/text())[1]','varchar(max)') as value
FROM m
CROSS APPLY xml.nodes('//p') as p(x)
WHERE x.value('(k/text())[1]','varchar(max)') = 'Attribute Name 2'
```

See this demonstrated in [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a45d6/73).

Comment: With bigger / more complex structures one should not shredd the whole lot into a derived table, just to use a `WHERE` at the the end. This filter should be part of an `XQuery`predicate...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml =
'<p>
  <k>Attribute Name</k>
  <v>Attribute Value</v>
<p>
<p>
  <k>Attribute Name 2</k>
  <k>Attribute Value 2</k>
</p>
<p>
  <k>Attribute Name 3</k>
  <k>Attribute Value 3</k>
<p>
<p>... and so on ...</p>'

SELECT
      a.value('@k[1]', 'varchar(max)') 
FROM @xml as a
```