# Retrieve xml elements from sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have xml stored in a sqlserver table column type as varchar. I need few elements from that xml string. Is there a way I can process this xml and store its elements in a table and retrieve when ever I need.

Comment: Check this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680259/parse-xml-in-sql-server/15681388) it may be what you're looking for

Comment: First of all: If you can change the column's type to XML, you really should. Storing XML in a string typed column is erronous and a pain in the neck. You might create a VIEW and read the values from the XML as one single SELECT call... But - if you need more help - you must provide more details...

Comment: @Shnugo Thank you so much for your response, so I have a table with a varchar column in it which stores xml in it. The table is updated every morning and I will have new rows to process and take some of the elements from that xml. XML has nested nodes. I have no clue how to flatten this xml and store the elements that I need to a different table, so that I can pull the data from this new table which has flattened xml data in it when ever am required to.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve], that is a *stand-alone* and *self-running* sample with input data, your own attempts and the expected output. As minimal as possible, but enough to understand your issues... What you provide is not enough to help you...